# Limit goes to infinity question: $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(x^6\left[e^{-\frac{1}{2x^3}}-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}\right)\right]\right)$

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(x^6\left[e^{-\frac{1}{2x^3}}-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}\right)\right]\right)$
Any tip on how to calculate it?

The solution is :$\frac{1}{12}$
I dont need the way to solution, just a tip on how to...
I have tried Taylor series, it wont work for me, I will get something really ugly and at the end, I  am still not managing to get rid of the $x^6$.
I tried doing taylor series of $e^x$, then instead of $x$ I put $\frac{1}{2x^3}$, but still wont work to me... any tip will be really favoured.

Comment: Sure about Taylor not working? I think you might want to give it another shot

Comment: Just expand as much as it takes, maybe a first order Taylor is not enough

Comment: I did order of 2 or 3 I think, I actually got to the x^6 in the denominator, but still didnt work. I will try again...

Comment: This definitely _can_ be done using the Taylor series for exp and cos.

Comment: I will try again.. I will do it more slowly now.. I will update.

Comment: Woot, actually I got it now,  I realzied my mistake... usually I dont like to work when the power is minus, so I do it 1\the exponent, I saw that was my mistake.. the taylor was good, but I could not get rid of the variable, now I managed, thanks guys!

Comment: You may close if needed :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. Keep in mind that these kind of exercises can all be done with Taylor. There are some which maybe cannot, counterexamples are always around the corner, but even if they existed you really need to cherrypick them

Comment: Thanks :D, I managed to solve lots of other now, I didnt realize my basic mistake lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, I always find that transforming the beast into a limit at zero is easier. Perform the substitution
$$
x^{3/2}=1/t
$$
so $x^3=1/t^2$ and $x^6=1/t^4$. Now the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{e^{-t^2/2}-\cos t}{t^4}
$$
and the Taylor expansion of the numerator up to degree $4$ is
$$
1-\frac{t^2/2}{1!}+\frac{t^4/4}{2!}-1+\frac{t^2}{2!}-\frac{t^4}{4!}+o(t^4)=\frac{t^4}{12}+o(t^4)
$$

Comment: Ahh, I already solved it, but thanks :)
That limit you did, atleast for me its more confusing, but I guess for others it is best :)
I will make this answer the most usefull so people can use to it learn, its actually good exercise for taylor + what you did with the limit, is a first timer for me at taylor, usually I am doing it without taylor when it has like 1/n and such, nice idea :)